# Como verificar se um campo de um array de chars está vazio em Java?

Tags: java, array, char

Estou tentando verificar se uma determinada posição de um array de chars contém efetivamente algum caractere.

Eu tentei de duas formas:

```
char[] arr = new char[10];

if(arr[0] == null){

}
```

E também:

```
char[] arr = new char[10];
if(arr[0] == ''){

}
```

Ao digitar qualquer uma das versões do código acima, o Netbeans aponta erro na comparação, mas não sugere correção.

Como eu posso fazer essa verificação?

Comment: Você precisa definir o que é vazio em primeiro lugar. Os dois casos não existem, um está perguntando se há uma referência nula, o que é impossível já que um `char` não é uma referência. O segundo está verificando se tem 0 charas, mas é certo que tem 1 `char` ali, você reservou espaço para ele, então tem, não há como não ter. Portanto o que é vazio? Essas duas condições são impossíveis.

Comment: Se verificar `arr[i] == 0` você checa se aquela posição está sendo utilizada, mas você precisa definir melhor mesmo o que quer como o Maniero disse.

Comment: Você fez `char[] arr = new char[10];` então o seu array tem 10 carateres e cada posição começa com o caratere `0` (`'\0'`) não confundir com o caratere `'0'`. E tem sempre que ter um caratere em cada posição.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta... Quero saber se contém algum caractere naquela posição ou se nada foi inserido ainda.

Comment: Conforme já foi falado 3 vezes, contém um caractere obrigatoriamente. Voc~e precisa então determinar o que você quer. Se só quer saber se contém algum caractere, não precisa fazer nada, já sabe que contém. Agora se quer saber se tem determinados caracteres específicos precisa definir isso.

Comment: @Isac, se você postar seu comentário como resposta eu registro como solucionado...

Comment: Isso daqui é um [**problema XY**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132). Por que é que você quer "*verificar se uma determinada posição de um array de chars contém efetivamente algum caractere*"? Onde você quer chegar com isso?

Comment: Num array de chars, **todas** as posições **sempre** tem um caractere. Isso acontece com qualquer array de tipos primitivos. Assim sendo, por que você quer fazer isso?

Comment: Obrigado por esclarecer isso Victor. Eu não sabia. Achava que cada espaço do array viria preenchido com "nada". Eu resolvi verificando se a posição tinha o caractere que eu procuro. (nesse array só teria aquele caractere que me interessa, o que tem no resto não importa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que não há uma representação de "vazio" para o tipo `char` que é primitivo, como `''`, então tem que analisar de outra forma. Olhei na documentação da classe `Character` e achei o [MIN_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MIN_VALUE) que é uma constante para o valor `'\u0000'` que no caso é `0` (zero).

Veja um exemplo:

```
import java.lang.*;

class Main 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    char[] arr = new char[] {'a','b', Character.MIN_VALUE};
    if (arr[1] == Character.MIN_VALUE)
    {
      System.out.println("vazio");
    }    
    else 
    {
      System.out.println("nao vazio");
    }
  }
}
```

Saída:

> nao vazio

Sendo assim, para fixar melhor veja esta tabela com valores padrão para todos os tipos primitivos:

[image: valores padrão]

<sup>[Fonte da tabela](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)</sup>

Se quiser valores "vazios" no array você pode usar esta constante. Há esta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8534178/5429980) também. Procura sempre dar prioridade para documentação nas suas pesquisas, se não tiver lá você pode perguntar aqui.